# How to use bundles in Sequel-Pro ?

Tags: mysql, sql, editor

Sequel Pro easy-to-use Mac database management application for working with MySQL databases. I want to know how to install bundles and use them in Sequel Pro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Download bundles (https://github.com/sequelpro/Bundles)
- Unzip the archive
- Double-click files with `.spBundle` extension for those bundles you want to use (or all of them)

You're done. You don't even need to restart SequelPro.